# Method added to Object.prototype repeats infinite times

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, for-in-loop

I was messing around with the browser console to improve my javascript skills.

When I tried to add a method to Object.prototype, that returns its instance as json, something odd happened:

Right at the end of the method, it jumps back to the for-in loop and execute it again. Over and over again...

It does not return anything and just continues to jump back and repeat.

The code:

```
Object.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var tempObj = {}; 
  for (let key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
      let value = this[key];
      tempObj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(tempObj); 
}
```

I know you should not add methods to Object.prototype. (If I'm wrong please correct me)

This is for learning purpose only.

### Can you please explain to me, why this method behaves like it does?

### I don't want to know, how it would work, but why it does not work. :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: `JSON.stringify` calls `toJSON` if it exists on an object (which now exists on EVERY object), and you've made `toJSON` call `JSON.stringify` ... the recursion is obvious

Comment: @JaromandaX that explains everything.. lmao
Thanks alot!

Comment: by the way, you can make it "work" by `var tempObj = Object.create(null);` - then `tempObj` is **not** an `Object` :p

Comment: Good to know! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `JSON.stringify()` whill check if the object have a method `toJSON`, it will call `toJSON` if there have one.

You replace the origin `toJSON` to yours, and in your `toJSON` called `JSON.stringify()`, so there create a call loop.

check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description